# How to get value from other selected documents and display value into one document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a list of document in view. I also have a button inside view where I can create new document with value from existed document. For this new document, I will use different form for new document created. In my view, document is divide by Status. I also has dialogBox too for me to set batchNo for new documents.

So, the process is like this:

1. First, I will select document based on it status. So let's say I have 5 documents under "Spoilt" status, I can choose how many document I want. So I choose 2 documents only.
2. After document selected, I will click button to create one new documents using lotusscript. After button clicked, DialogBox will show. I insert batchNo and click OK.
3. Then, the code will check that status of documents and create new document by getting value from 3 documents and display into new document.
4. For example, I need to get value from field "PSerialNo" and "PType" from 2 documents. As you can see below. Value from document1 and document2, I want to insert in new document. So if document1, PSerialNo into WSerialNo1 and PType into WType1. And if document2, PSerialNo into WSerialNo2 and PType into WType2 and so on.

**Document 1**
[image: doc1]
**Document 2**
[image: doc2]
**New Document**
[image: newdoc]

This is my code to create new document.

```
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()

While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.PStatus(0) = "Active" Then
        Set newdoc = New NotesDocument(db)
        newdoc.Form = "WriteOff"            

        newdoc.WABatchNo = wDialogDoc.WBatchNo(0)
        newdoc.WType = doc.PType(0)
        newdoc.WSerialNo = doc.PSerialNo(0)

        newdoc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
        newdoc.save(True,False)

    End If
    doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

My problem now, if I create new document, and I want to get value from two documents, it not insert into one new document but it insert into two different new document. How can I fix it. Any advice or help I appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been more than 10 years since I wrote LotusScript, so I might be wrong.

```
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()
Dim docCreated As Boolean 'flag a document was created
Dim i As Integer 'index for each document

docCreated = False
i = 0
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.PStatus(0) = "Active" Then
        If Not docCreated Then 'only create a document for first doc
            Set newdoc = New NotesDocument(db)
            newdoc.Form = "WriteOff"
            docCreated = True
        End If
        i = i + 1

        newdoc.WABatchNo = wDialogDoc.WBatchNo(0)
        ' not sure about this part, but the idea is to set WType1 for first doc, WType2 for 2nd doc, and so on
        Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("WType" & i, doc.PType(0))
        Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("WSerialNo" & i, doc.PSerialNo(0))
    End If
    doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend

If docCreated Then
    Call newdoc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
    Call newdoc.save(True,False)
End If
```

Comment: Hey thanks for giving your answer. I alreay try your solution but it seem GetItemValue is not right as it show error to required variable for it. Any idea on that? Also in If docCreated, need to Call for both ComputeWithForm and save. :)

Comment: Okay nevermind I fixed it. I will update on your answer